# Spring - cURLS not deserializing with Jackson XML Mapper

Tags: java, json, xml, spring, curl

I'm trying to set up my web service so that I can serialize and deserialize with json and xml interchangeably.

I have the controllers set up to handle calls:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/profiles/users/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {"application/json", "application/xml"}, consumes = {"application/json", "application/xml"})
public WebServiceResponse getIndividualUser(@PathVariable int id){
    WebServicePayload payload = new WebServicePayload(personService.findById(id));
    List list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Person Retrieved");
    return new WebServiceResponse(new WebServiceResponseStatus(WebServiceResponseStatus.Request.Successful, list), payload);
}
```

Then I attempt to deserialize my objects with cURL statements:

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accepts: application/json" http://localhost:8080/user-profile-ws/profiles/users/1.json
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -H "Accepts: application/xml" http://localhost:8080/user-profile-ws/profiles/users/1.xml
```

The error i'm getting is

> The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.

The error it's self sounds straight forward but I can't see to figure it out. I know that my accept headers are correct in my cURL and my controller so i'm not sure what the problem is. I'm in the process of migrating away from jaxb to use jackson's xml marshaling, so I thought the issue might be with how i'm adding the converters to spring. The json aspect is working correctly, it's just the xml that's causing the error.

I add my converters to spring like so(in my servlet config class):

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(getMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    converters.add(getMappingJacksonXmlConverter());
    super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
}

public HttpMessageConverter<?> getMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    return new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(getJackson2ObjectMapperBuilder().build());
}

public HttpMessageConverter<?> getMappingJacksonXmlConverter() {
    return new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(getJacksonXmlObjectMapper());
}

@Bean(name = "xmlMapper")
public XmlMapper getJacksonXmlObjectMapper() {
    XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
    mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    return mapper;
}

@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder getJackson2ObjectMapperBuilder() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    builder.indentOutput(true).dateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    builder.autoDetectFields(true);
    builder.autoDetectGettersSetters(true);
    builder.annotationIntrospector(getJacksonAnnotationIntrospector());
    return builder;
}
```

as far as I know I added them correctly but I can't see what's causing the error.

Any help is appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to fix the issue, I just had to add supported mediaTypes to the message converter.

```
public HttpMessageConverter<?> getMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(getJackson2ObjectMapperBuilder().build());
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(getSupportedJsonMediaTypes());
    return converter;
}

public HttpMessageConverter<?> getMappingJacksonXmlConverter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(getJacksonXmlObjectMapper());
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(getSupportedXmlMediaTypes());
    return converter;
}

private List<MediaType> getSupportedJsonMediaTypes() {
    List<MediaType> mediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
    mediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    return mediaTypes;
}

private List<MediaType> getSupportedXmlMediaTypes() {
    List<MediaType> mediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
    mediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    return mediaTypes;
}
```

Then it worked like charm

Answer (score 0):

What about add `@ReponseBody` to `public WebServiceResponse getIndividualUser` method?

Also having `consumes` part in GET method or send `Content-Type` in curl Request does not make sense (it does not consume/sending anything).

Comment: My controller is annotated with `@RestController` which should add `@ResponseBody` to all of the methods inside